# C#: How to change XAtrribute given the Value of its parent's sibling node

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I've started learning C# and I'm creating an forms app to automate some data entry in my job using LINQ to XML. What I'd like to do is change the attribute of an element if that element's parent has a sibling with a specific value.

I'd like to change the "rValue" attribute of the Type element in all Wall elements except those with a Label value of "Garage Wall". I want these to be a different value. Sometimes a Garage Wall is not present however.

Here is an example of the XML I want to edit

```
<House>
   <Components>
      <Wall id="17">
        <Label>Garage Wall</Label>
        <Construction corners="3">
          <Type rValue="2.6822">User specified</Type>
        </Construction>
        <Measurements height="2.7706" perimeter="6.5014" />
        <FacingDirection code="1">
        </FacingDirection>
      </Wall>
   </Components>
</House>
```

This is the code I have at the moment which only applies changes to all Wall elements.

```
public XDocument RChanger(XDocument house, decimal rValue, decimal garWallRValue)
{
  string wallType = "Garage Wall";

     foreach (XElement wall in house.Descendants("Wall"))
     {
       if (wallType == wall.Value.ToString())
         {
           foreach (XElement type in wall.Descendants("Type"))
             {
               type.SetAttributeValue("rValue", garWallRValue);
              }
          }
           else 
             foreach (XElement type in wall.Descendants("Type"))
              {
                type.SetAttributeValue("rValue", rValue.ToString());
               }
       }
 return house;
}
```

The way it's written right now seems like even if the IF statement worked, the else would just overwrite the attribute. The result I get with this is all walls having the same "rValue" attribute in the Type element.

I'm a beginner so I apologize if there's a concept I need to learn that I'm missing.

EDIT:
I've got it to work with the following:

```
string wallType = "Garage Wall";
foreach(XElement wall in house.Descendants("Wall"))
            {
                //Check for garage walls
                foreach(XElement type in wall.Descendants("Type"))
                if (wallType.Equals(wall.Element("Label").Value.ToString()))
                {
                        //if wall is a garage wall
                    type.SetAttributeValue("rValue", "2.92");
                }
                else
                {
                        //if wall is not a garage wall
                    type.SetAttributeValue("rValue", "3.080");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, however it assumes that each Wall element meets some criteria:

- They **always** contain a **single** type element
- They have either zero or one label element

```cs
public XDocument RChanger(XDocument house, decimal rValue, decimal garWallRValue)
{
    string wallType = "Garage Wall";
    foreach (var element in house.Descendants("Wall")) {
        var type = element.Descendants("Type").Single();
        if (element.Descendants("Label").SingleOrDefault()?.Value == wallType) {
            // If the label of the element is not the wall type
            type.SetAttributeValue("rValue", garWallRValue);
        } else {
            type.SetAttributeValue("rValue", rValue);
        }
    }
    return house;
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vcz3fd

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Unfortunately some Walls do contain child elements that have type elements of their own so this created some errors. I'll keep looking down this path though.